# AddEventListener is giving error in my angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, addeventlistener

Can anyone help here or am i writing wrong syntax

```
  //This below giving Error 
    const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".home_highlights_list")!;
    scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt): any => {
     evt.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the "!" at the end of your first line ?

Comment: Ts does not have access to the DOM, so use non-null operator, ! to tell ts the expression isn't null or undefined

Comment: what is the error it is giving? Add the error to the post so people can help more!